# Convert promises to callbacks

Tags: javascript, promise, callback

This sounds like weird requirements since it's only with the purpose of learning Promise.

I started to use Promise before callback hell... so writing promise is easier and more natural. However I heard promise solved the callback hell issue, so I am trying to convert the following block to the callback hell way to understand promise deeper.
The log result will be (2+2)*2/2 = 4

```
const sum = (a,b) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve(a+b), 500)
    })
}
const multiply = c => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve(c*2), 600)
    })
}

const divide = d => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve(d/2), 700)
    })
}

sum(2,2).then(multiply).then(divide).then(console.log); //4
```

Trying to write the above block in the callback way.
I learned a callback function is usually used as a parameter to another function. The function that receives the callback function as a parameter is normally completing a task(e.g network request) that could block the code for a notable amount of time.
So I passed the `multiply` as the callback to `sum` and hope that the value of c will be the sum of a and b, however I got `Uncaught ReferenceError: c is not defined`.

Please advice how can we make the callback hell work and log the same result.

```
function sum(a,b,multiply) {
  multiply(a+b);
}

function multiply(c, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => callback(c*2), 600)
}

function divide(d, callback){
    setTimeout(() => console.log(callback(d/2)), 700)
}

function run(){
  sum(2,2, function(){
    multiply(c, function() {
      divide(d)
    })
  })
}

run()
```

Comment: Well inside your `run` function `c` and `d` are not defined. You also didn't provide a callback to the `divide` function.

Comment: @Reyno  my intention is `c` is the return value of `a+b` , that is 2+2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an admirable idea to learn this way, but the other thing to learn is that, just like programing, experimentation requires precision.

Turn your experiment into a "controlled experiment" by being precise about what's standardized between the functions in each style (trial), and what changes between the two trials.  First, three identically formed promise operations...

```js
function sum(a, b) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(a+b), 200))
}

function multiply(a, b) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(a*b), 200))
}

function divide(a, b) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(a/b), 200))
}

function run() {
  // 2+3 == 5, 5*6 == 30, 30/3 == 10
  return sum(2,3)
    .then(s => multiply(s,6))
    .then(p => divide(p,3))
    .then(console.log);
}

run()
```

(note also the more selective use of operands so you can see the math working... instead of two plus two times two divided by two, which has too many ways of concealing errors)

Now the same three, identically formed, using callbacks...

```js
function sum(a, b, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => callback(a+b), 200);
}

function multiply(a, b, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => callback(a*b), 200);
}

function divide(a, b, callback){
  setTimeout(() => callback(a/b), 200);
}

function run(){
  // 2+3 == 5, 5*6 == 30, 30/3 == 10
  sum(2, 3, 
    sum => multiply(sum, 6, 
      product => divide(product, 3,
        result => console.log(result))));
}

run()
```